# Can't install Linux Mint Cinnamon nor Ubuntu while switchable graphics turned on

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, drivers, desktop, graphics

I've got Lenovo G500 intel i5 with switchable graphics (Intel and AMD Radeon HD 8579M).
When I try to install Linux Mint Petra Cinnamon, when switchable graphics are on by the bios, live CD can't start Xserver and crashes (blue screen. "want to see log files?" etc.).

I have tried to install Ubuntu (Saucy Salamander) too and got only black screen (can't get to command line interface).

I have managed to install Mint Cinnamon with turning off switchable graphics. After that I tried to install a working desktop while SG on.

Ubuntu crashed, KDE Plasma works only in fallback mode.

While switchable graphics are turned on, only Xubuntu works.

On Xubuntu I had tried to install `fglrx` via distribution packages, installers and `apt-get`, but my every attempt has been failed.

There is no buildpkg for AMD driver Ubuntu/Saucy

```
amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

nor in

```
amd-catalyst-13.11-beta_V9.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

I tried to add repository, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer

E: could not locate the package
```

Right now I uninstalled every bit of `fglrx` and turned off SG. I'm now using Cinnamon.